# Is set of all surjections from $\mathbb{N} \cap m+1$ to finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set of all surjections from $\{1,…,m\}$ to $\{1,…,n\}$ is finite.
But Set of all surjections from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is not finite.
So I thought this intermediate:

Is $\{$ $f$ $|$ $f$$ : \mathbb{N} \cap (m+1)(=\{1,…,m\}) \to$ finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ $\wedge$ f is surjection $ \}$ finite set?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I had made a serious mistake.I added word, "finite subset".

Comment: There is no surjection from $\{1,2,...,m\} $ to $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's empty in fact:) Note the domain is finite, and the range is countably infinite.

Comment: @CameronBuie right indeed! editing

Comment: I'm afraid this is complicated.
$\mathbb{N}$ is not range but codomain.
But these are the same notation, hence I cannot fix it.

Comment: @hinalogic: "Surjection" _means_ that you want the range to be equal to the codomain.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Should I wrote "$\{1,…,m\}$ to subset of $\mathbb{N}$"?

Comment: @hinalogic: What do you _intend_ for the word "surjection" to achieve in your question? A "surjection from $Y$ to a subset of $X$" is just the same as a "map from $Y$ to $X$" -- there is no point in speaking of surjections unless you care what the range is.

Comment: f : {0,1,2} $\to$ {0,1} is surjection from $3$ to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.
But this isn't map from 3 to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @hinalogic: Please share with us your definition of "map from $3$ to $\mathbb N$", which sounds like it must be different from the usual one.

Comment: I apologize. I have confused.
f : {0,1,2} → {0,1} is map from 3 to N. 
But {f | f : 3 $\to$ subset of N and f is surjection} is proper subset of set of all map from 3 to N.
I wish to know cardinality of {f | f : m $\to$ subset of N and f is surjection}.

Comment: @hina: You are wrong. A map from $3$ to $\mathbb N$ is _exactly the same_ as a surjection from $3$ to some subset of $\mathbb N$. If you disagree, please show a _concrete example_ of something that is one of those but is not the other. Also explain what your definitions are, since at least one of them must be non-standard.

Comment: I understand at last.
subset of N include N.
I should wrote a surjection from 3 to some "finite" subset of N.
It is established by this.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is infiite and $\{1,2,3,...,m\}$ is finite, surjections from the latter to the former are impossible. Otherwise, we would be claiming that $\mathbb{N}$'s size is smaller or equal than $\{1,2,3,...,m\}$'s, which is absurd